# How do I make a decimal alignments with powered number?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

could you please help me to make decimal alignments with powered number? Thanks in advance

In attachment, you can find the current view table[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rccol}
\rcDecimalSign{.}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,adjustbox}
\def\MC#1{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h!]
\caption{Results with different numerical schemes for the simple Cartesian trajectory}
  \label{Table:02}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{cccR{2}{2}ccccc} \hline
        Radius of platforms \\ Vs Limb lengths  &  Numerical Scheme &      &  \MC{}  &     & Errors    &    &   &     \\ \cline{4-9}
   &  &  &  \MC{$\pmb{g}_x[\rm{mm}]$} &  $\pmb{g}_y[\rm{mm}]$ & $\pmb{g}_z[\rm{mm}]$ & $\pmb{g}_{\psi}[^{\circ}]$ & $\pmb{g}_{\theta}[^{\circ}]$  & $\pmb{g}_{\phi}[^{\circ}]$ \\ \hline
      \\
                 $\mathbf {1:1}$       & Constant Jacobian & max & 0.011   & 0.208 & $0.431$ & 0.007 & 0.029 & 0.006 \\ 
                          &                                                & min & -1.666 &    -0.208 & -0.223 & -0.007 & -0.035 & -0.006 \\               
          $\sigma_{max}$   (1.08) &   Updated Jacobian & max &    0.00 & $2.9\cdot{10^{-4}}$ & $7.1\cdot{10^{-4}}$&  $4.3\cdot{10^{-6}}$ &  $2.4\cdot{10^{-5}}$&  $3.8\cdot{10^{-6}}$ \\
                                                                      &      & min &  -0.00 &  $-2.9\cdot{10^{-4}}$ & $-5.6\cdot{10^{-4}}$ &  $-4.3\cdot{10^{-6}}$ &  $-2.4\cdot{10^{5}}$ &  $-3.8\cdot{10^{-6}}$ \\
 $\sigma_{min}$ (0.54)      & Newton-Raphson Method   & max &  $2.3\cdot{10^{-14}}$  & $1.1\cdot{10^{-9}}$ &  $7.9\cdot{10^{-10}}$ &  $1.0\cdot{10^{-12}}$ &  $4.1\cdot{10^{-12}}$  &  $2.7\cdot{10^{-13}}$ \\
                                                  &                          & min &$-3.5\cdot{10^{-9}}$ & $-1.1\cdot{10^{-9}}$ & $-1.3\cdot{10^{-9}}$ & $-1.0\cdot{10^{-12}}$ & $-1.6\cdot{10^{-14}}$ & $-2.8\cdot{10^{-13}}$\\ \hline
                \\
                    $\mathbf  {1:2}$     & Constant Jacobian  & max & 0.012 & 0.397&  $0.847$ & 0.008& 0.039 & 0.006 \\
                                                                       &       & min &$-2.396$ & -0.397& -0.448 & -0.008 & -0.045 & -0.006 
                \\
             $\sigma_{max}$  (1.65)     & Updated Jacobian & max &  $5.3\cdot{10^{-6}}$ &  $1.3\cdot{10^{-4}}$ &  $2.9\cdot{10^{-4}}$ &  $3.9\cdot{10^{-6}}$ &  $1.7\cdot{10^{-5}}$&  $3.1\cdot{10^{-6}}$ \\
                                                           &                  & min &  -0.001 &  $-1.4\cdot{10^{-4}}$ &  $-2.1\cdot{10^{-1}}$ &  $-3.9\cdot{10^{6}}$ &   $-1.8\cdot{10^{-5}}$ & $-3.1\cdot{10^{-6}}$\\
  $\sigma_{min}$ (0.44)        & Newton-Raphson Method  &max &  $3.9\cdot{10^{-14}}$ &   $4.7\cdot{10^{-10}}$ &  $2.7\cdot{10^{-10}}$ &  $5.9\cdot{10^{-13}}$ &  $8.5\cdot{10^{-13}}$ &  $1.9\cdot{10^{-13}}$ \\
                                                           &                  &min & $-2.6\cdot{10^{-10}}$ & $-4.8\cdot{10^{-10}}$ &  $-6.8\cdot{10^{-10}}$ &  $-6.0\cdot{10^{-13}}$ &  $-3.9\cdot{10^{-14}}$ &  $-1.8\cdot{10^{-13}}$ \\ \hline 
                \\
                       $\mathbf{1:3}$     &  Constant Jacobian & max & 0.011 & 0.208 &$0.431$ & 0.007 & 0.029 & 0.006 \\
                                                              &               & min & -1.666 & -0.208 & $-0.223$ & -0.007 & -0.035  & -0.006 \\
      $\sigma_{max}$ (2.34)           & Updated Jacobian  & max &  $4.8\cdot{10^{-6}}$ &  $7.1\cdot{10^{-5}}$ &  $1.5\cdot{10^{-4}}$ &  $3.62\cdot{10^{-6}}$ & $1.3\cdot{10^{-5}}$ &  $3.1\cdot{10^{-6}}$ \\
                                                       &                     & min &  $-7.3\cdot{10^{-4}}$ &  $-7.1\cdot{10^{-5}}$ &  $-1.0\cdot{10^{-4}}$ &  $-3.6\cdot{10^{-6}}$ &   $-1.4\cdot{10^{-5}}$ &  $-3.1\cdot{10^{-6}}$ \\
 $\sigma_{min}$ (0.43)       & Newton-Raphson Method  & max &  $2.8\cdot{10^{-14}}$ & $2.1\cdot{10^{-10}}$ &  $1.17\cdot{10^{-10}}$ &  $1.03\cdot{10^{-9}}$ &  $2.8\cdot{10^{-13}}$ &  $1.4\cdot{10^{-13}}$\\
                                                                 &              &min &  $-2.1\cdot{10^{-9}}$ & $-2.2\cdot{10^{-10}}$ &  $-3.1\cdot{10^{-10}}$ &  $-1.0\cdot{10^{-9}}$ &  $-5.2\cdot{10^{-14}}$ &  $-1.2\cdot{10^{-13}}$\\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{adjustbox}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: for numbers use `S` column type?

Comment: user128106, any news?

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

[image]

I suggest to use `S` column type from `siunitx`, also all units wrote with it and for horizontal lines use  `booktabs`. For table environment the `tabularx` seems to be better solution than use `tabular` and then it squeeze to text width:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%\usepackage{rccol}
%\rcDecimalSign{.}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\def\MC#1{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\caption{Results with different numerical schemes for the simple Cartesian trajectory}
    \label{Table:02}
%\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}X 
                                     >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X 
                                                        c 
                                     *{6}{S[table-format=-1.1,
                                            table-figures-exponent=2,
                                            exponent-product = \cdot,
                                            table-sign-exponent                     
                                            ]}
                                @{}} 
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{=}[-0.5ex]{Rad. of platforms vs Limb lengths}  
    &  \multirow{2}{=}[-0.5ex]{Numerical Scheme} 
        &   &  \multicolumn{6}{c}{Errors}                               \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){4-9}
    &   &   &   {$\pmb{g}_x$ [mm]} 
                &  {$\pmb{g}_y$ [mm]} 
                    &   {$\pmb{g}_z$ [mm]} 
                        &   {$\pmb{g}_{\psi}$ [\si{\degree}]} 
                            &   {$\pmb{g}_{\theta}$ [\si{\degree}]} 
                                &  {$\pmb{g}_{\phi}$ [\si{\degree}]}                \\ 
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{=}{$\mathbf{1:1}$}       
    & \multirow{2}{=}{Constant Jacobian} 
        & max &  0.011  &  0.208    &  0.431    &  0.007    &  0.029    &  0.006    \\
    &   & min & -1.666  & -0.208    & -0.223    & -0.007    & -0.035    & -0.006    \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{$\sigma_{max}$   (1.08)} 
    & \multirow{2}{=}{Updated Jacobian} 
        & max &  0.00   &  2.9e-4   &  7.1e-4   &  4.3e-6   &  2.4e-5   & 3.8e-6    \\
    &   & min & -0.00   & -2.9e-4   & -5.6e-4   & -4.3e-6   & -2.4e5    &-3.8e-6    \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{$\sigma_{min}$ (0.54)}      
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{Newton-Raphson}   
        & max & 2.3e-14 & 1.1e-9    &  7.9e-10  &  1.0e-12  &  4.1e-12  &  2.7e-13  \\
    &   & min &-3.5e-9  &-1.1e-9    & -1.3e-9   & -1.0e-12  & -1.6e-14  & -2.8e-13  \\ \midrule
    \end{tabularx}
%    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Scaling arbitrarily a table should be the last resort. Better trying to squeeze it at the maximum, using abbreviations for large repetitive bits:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h!]

\newcommand{\G}[2]{{$\bm{g}_{#1}$ (\si{#2})}} % temporary for the table
\newcommand{\CJ}{CJ}
\newcommand{\UJ}{UJ}
\newcommand{\NRM}{NR}
\newcommand{\smax}[1]{$\sigma_{\max}$ (#1)}
\newcommand{\smin}[1]{$\sigma_{\min}$ (#1)}
\newcommand{\rt}[1]{$\mathbf{#1}$}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{E}}}

\caption{Results with different numerical schemes for the simple Cartesian trajectory}
\label{Table:02}

\scriptsize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.4pt}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l c l
  *{6}{S[table-format=-1.2e1]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
(a) & (b)
& & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Errors} \\
\cmidrule(l){4-9}
 &  &  &  \G{x}{mm} & \G{y}{mm} & \G{z}{mm} &
          \G{\psi}{\degree} & \G{\theta}{\degree}& \G{\phi}{\degree} \\
\midrule
\rt{1:1}    & \CJ  & max &  0.011   &  0.208  &  0.431     &  0.007   &  0.029   &  0.006   \\ 
            &      & min & -1.666   & -0.208  & -0.223     & -0.007   & -0.035   & -0.006   \\
\smax{1.08} & \UJ  & max &  0.00    &  2.9e-4 &  7.1e-4    &  4.3e-6  &  2.4e-5  &  3.8e-6  \\
            &      & min & -0.00    & -2.9e-4 & -5.6e-4    & -4.3e-6  & -2.4e5   & -3.8e-6  \\
\smin{0.54} & \NRM & max &  2.3e-14 &  1.1e-9 &  7.9e-10   &  1.0e-12 &  4.1e-12 &  2.7e-13 \\
            &      & min & -3.5e-9  & -1.1e-9 & -1.3e-9    & -1.0e-12 & -1.6e-14 & -2.8e-13 \\
\midrule
\rt{1:2}    & \CJ  & max &  0.012   &  0.397   &  0.847    &  0.008   &  0.039   &  0.006   \\
            &      & min & -2.396   & -0.397   & -0.448    & -0.008   & -0.045   & -0.006   \\
\smax{1.65} & \UJ  & max &  5.3e-6  &  1.3e-4  &  2.9e-4   &  3.9e-6  &  1.7e-5  &  3.1e-6  \\
            &      & min & -0.001   & -1.4e-4  & -2.1e-1   & -3.9e6   & -1.8e-5  & -3.1e-6  \\
\smin{0.44} & \NRM & max &  3.9e-14 &  4.7e-10 &  2.7e-10  &  5.9e-13 &  8.5e-13 &  1.9e-13 \\
            &      & min & -2.6e-10 & -4.8e-10 & -6.8e-10  & -6.0e-13 & -3.9e-14 & -1.8e-13 \\
\midrule
\rt{1:3}    & \CJ  & max &  0.011   &  0.208   &  0.431    &  0.007   &  0.029   &  0.006   \\
            &      & min & -1.666   & -0.208   & -0.223    & -0.007   & -0.035   & -0.006   \\
\smax{2.34} & \UJ  & max &  4.8e-6  &  7.1e-5  &  1.5e-4   &  3.62e-6 &  1.3e-5  &  3.1e-6  \\
            &      & min & -7.3e-4  & -7.1e-5  & -1.0e-4   & -3.6e-6  & -1.4e-5  & -3.1e-6  \\
\smin{0.43} & \NRM & max &  2.8e-14 &  2.1e-10 &  1.17e-10 &  1.03e-9 &  2.8e-13 &  1.4e-13 \\
            &      & min & -2.1e-9  & -2.2e-10 & -3.1e-10  & -1.0e-9  & -5.2e-14 & -1.2e-13 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize\strut (a): Radius of platforms vs. limb lengths} \\
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize\strut (b): Numerical Scheme} \\
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize\strut \CJ: Constant Jacobian, \UJ: Updated Jacobian,
                         \NRM: Newton-Raphson Method}
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Depending on the real document's text width you may be able to enlarge the table. I used the `x.yEz` scientific notation because it's more economic in space than the “times 10 at” one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses the `dcolumn` package to achieve alignment on the decimal markers. It also uses a `tabular*` environment instead of `tabular`, and it manages to typeset the entire table without having to resort to shrinking the font size. And, since you're already loading the `bm` package, it uses `\bm` rather than `\pmb` in various places.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,ragged2e,siunitx,booktabs,dcolumn}
\def\MC#1{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\mytab}[1]{\smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\newcommand\mycdot{\mkern1mu{\cdot}\mkern1mu}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h!]
%\small
\caption{Results with different numerical schemes for the simple Cartesian trajectory}
\label{Table:02}
\medskip

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out amount of intercolumn whitespace
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lll *{5}{d{2.6}} d{2.7} }
\toprule
\mytab{Radius of\\platforms vs\\limb lengths} &  
\mytab{Numerical\\Scheme} & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Errors} \\
\cmidrule(l){4-9}
& & &  
\MC{$\bm{g}_x$ [\si{\milli\meter}]} & \MC{$\bm{g}_y$ [\si{\milli\meter}]} &
\MC{$\bm{g}_z$ [\si{\milli\meter}]} & \MC{$\bm{g}_{\psi}$ [\si{\celsius}]} &
\MC{$\bm{g}_{\psi}$ [\si{\celsius}]} & \MC{$\bm{g}_{\psi}$ [\si{\celsius}]}
\\ \addlinespace\addlinespace
\midrule
 \textbf{1 : 1} & \mytab{Constant\\Jacobian} & max & 0.011  & 0.208 & 0.431 & 0.007 & 0.029 & 0.006 \\
   & & min & -1.666 &  -0.208 & -0.223 & -0.007 & -0.035 & -0.006 \\ \addlinespace
 $\sigma_{\max}$ (1.08) & \mytab{Updated\\Jacobian} & max &  0.00 & 2.9\mycdot10^{-4} & 7.1\mycdot10^{-4}&  4.3\mycdot10^{-6} &  2.4\mycdot10^{-5}&  3.8\mycdot10^{-6} \\
   & & min &  -0.00 &  -2.9\mycdot10^{-4} & -5.6\mycdot10^{-4} &  -4.3\mycdot10^{-6} &  -2.4\mycdot10^{5} &  -3.8\mycdot10^{-6} \\ \addlinespace
 $\sigma_{\min}$ (0.54) & \mytab{N-R\\Method} & max &  2.3\mycdot10^{-14}  & 1.1\mycdot10^{-9} &  7.9\mycdot10^{-10} &  1.0\mycdot10^{-12} &  4.1\mycdot10^{-12}  &  2.7\mycdot10^{-13} \\
   & & min &-3.5\mycdot10^{-9} & -1.1\mycdot10^{-9} & -1.3\mycdot10^{-9} & -1.0\mycdot10^{-12} & -1.6\mycdot10^{-14} & -2.8\mycdot10^{-13}\\
\midrule
 \textbf{1 : 2} & \mytab{Constant\\Jacobian}  & max & 0.012 & 0.397&  0.847 & 0.008& 0.039 & 0.006 \\
   & & min &-2.396 & -0.397& -0.448 & -0.008 & -0.045 & -0.006 \\ \addlinespace
 $\sigma_{\max}$ (1.65) & \mytab{Updated\\Jacobian} & max &  5.3\mycdot10^{-6} &  1.3\mycdot10^{-4} &  2.9\mycdot10^{-4} &  3.9\mycdot10^{-6} &  1.7\mycdot10^{-5}&  3.1\mycdot10^{-6} \\
   & & min &  -0.001 &  -1.4\mycdot10^{-4} &  -2.1\mycdot{10^{-1}} &  -3.9\mycdot10^{6} &   -1.8\mycdot10^{-5} & -3.1\mycdot10^{-6}\\ \addlinespace
 $\sigma_{\min}$ (0.44) & \mytab{N-R\\Method}  &max &  3.9\mycdot10^{-14} &   4.7\mycdot10^{-10} &  2.7\mycdot10^{-10} &  5.9\mycdot10^{-13} &  8.5\mycdot10^{-13} &  1.9\mycdot10^{-13} \\
   & & min & -2.6\mycdot10^{-10} & -4.8\mycdot10^{-10} &  -6.8\mycdot10^{-10} &  -6.0\mycdot10^{-13} &  -3.9\mycdot10^{-14} &  -1.8\mycdot10^{-13} \\
\midrule
 \textbf{1 : 3} &  \mytab{Constant\\Jacobian} & max & 0.011 & 0.208 &0.431 & 0.007 & 0.029 & 0.006 \\
   & & min & -1.666 & -0.208 & -0.223 & -0.007 & -0.035  & -0.006 \\ \addlinespace
 $\sigma_{\max}$ (2.34) & \mytab{Updated\\Jacobian} & max &  4.8\mycdot10^{-6} &  7.1\mycdot10^{-5} &  1.5\mycdot10^{-4} &  3.62\mycdot10^{-6} & 1.3\mycdot10^{-5} &  3.1\mycdot10^{-6} \\
   & & min &  -7.3\mycdot10^{-4} &  -7.1\mycdot10^{-5} &  -1.0\mycdot10^{-4} &  -3.6\mycdot10^{-6} &   -1.4\mycdot10^{-5} &  -3.1\mycdot10^{-6} \\ \addlinespace
 $\sigma_{\min}$ (0.43) & \mytab{N-R\\Method}  & max &  2.8\mycdot10^{-14} & 2.1\mycdot10^{-10} &  1.17\mycdot10^{-10} &  1.03\mycdot10^{-9} &  2.8\mycdot10^{-13} &  1.4\mycdot10^{-13}\\
   & &min &  -2.1\mycdot10^{-9} & -2.2\mycdot10^{-10} &  -3.1\mycdot10^{-10} &  -1.0\mycdot10^{-9} &  -5.2\mycdot10^{-14} &  -1.2\mycdot10^{-13}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```